# Is there a way to differentiate between location / {} and location /index {} in nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-proxy, nginx-location

I am stuck between these two :

```
location / { 
#proxy pass to some other location that handles all urls except /index
}
location /index {
    #logic to handle the index
 }
```

Currently when i run nginx first

location / 
block gets executed and i get redirected to other machine and

location /index 
is not getting called.Is there a way to differentiate between these two or i have to specifically write all locations.

Comment: location `/index` will be executed only when you make a request like `example.com/index` otherwise `/` location will be executed

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a difference.
location /{} handle all urls. but when you put location /index {} it means your location /{} handles all urls except /index

Now when you hit domain url(www.example.com) your this location /{} block handles url, but when you hit domain/index, your location /index {} block handle url.
location /index is not getting called until and unless you hit domain/index(www.example.com/index)

hope you get your answer

Comment: got it ! nginx picks up the longest matching pattern first and if route doesnot get resolved it checks shorter one